# Invalid query: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians'

Tags: php

I am trying to create store locator as explained on google and [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](http://imagine-it.org/google/articles/phpsqlsearch.htm)

But I am stuck with this error msg:

> Invalid query: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native
>   function 'radians'

I saw one question posted but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a function that requires a set number of parameters, and you have the wrong number.  Without showing your code it's tough to tell what you did wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should look for another script. The one afer "The PHP file that does all that is shown below" has problems galore: uses deprecated mysql_* functions, doesn't check input parameters, is prone to sql injections, only rudimentary error handling, ....